# Denoising in viewport?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, 3d-view, noise-reduction, denoise

Is it possible to enable the new (2.79b) denoising feature in the viewport? It works great for me in renders, but I can't find a way to apply it in the viewport.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Denoiser works with algorithms done via feature passes and final image data. It's currently not implemented for the viewport nor for progressively refined renders.

[Official Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html)